# iOS Sqlite3 Delete Query Not Deleting Row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am using this code to delete a row from the database for my ipad application,

```
-(BOOL) removeSegmentWithSegmentId:(NSInteger)sId
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *removeKeyword =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM segment WHERE segment.segment_id = %d",sId];
    const char *query = [removeKeyword UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"%@",removeKeyword);

    //if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate->globalConnection,[removeKeyword UTF8String] , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate->globalConnection,query , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

but it is not working, can anyone guide me please?

Comment: I bet you're trying to delete from a database residing in the app bundle...

Comment: no this is not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your method returning YES?

A couple of things:

- Always log `sqlite3_errmsg` on any failures
- Right now, you're only doing `sqlite3_finalize` is `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_DONE`, whereas you really should be doing it whenever you successfully did `sqlite3_prepare_v2`

So, I might suggest, at a minimum:

```
-(BOOL) removeSegmentWithSegmentId:(NSInteger)sId
{
    BOOL success = NO;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *removeKeyword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM segment WHERE segment.segment_id = %d",sId];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate->globalConnection, [removeKeyword UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            success = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: step not ok: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate->globalConnection));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failure: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate->globalConnection));
    }

    return success;
}
```

Assuming this method was always returning `YES`, if you're not seeing records deleted, it must be that it's not finding a record to delete. (That is not considered a SQLite failure. The SQL was successfully executed, but the `WHERE` clause couldn't be satisfied.) You can verify this by defining the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)countSegmentWithSegmentId:(NSInteger)sId
{
    NSInteger count = 0;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT segment_id FROM segment WHERE segment.segment_id = %d", sId];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate->globalConnection, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
            count++;

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failure: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate->globalConnection));
        return -1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

And then put the diagnostic message in `removeSegmentWithSegmentId`:

```
- (BOOL)removeSegmentWithSegmentId:(NSInteger)sId
{
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSInteger count = [self countSegmentWithSegmentId:sId];

    NSLog(@"%s there are %d records with segment_id of %d", __FUNCTION__, count, sId);

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *removeKeyword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM segment WHERE segment.segment_id = %d",sId];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate->globalConnection, [removeKeyword UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            success = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: step not ok: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate->globalConnection));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failure: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate->globalConnection));
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
{
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            return YES;
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Failed to delete row %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

check the error msg.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

Steps are

1.Open database

2.Delete row from table

3.Close database

Also added NSLog to view the error in console

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method : checkAndCreateDatabase
// Method to Check and Create the database
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Function to check & create a database
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    //-------------------------------------------
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cDatabasePath];
    //-------------------------------------------
    //databse already there
    if(success)
    {
        return;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------
    //create database
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:cDatabaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:cDatabasePath error:nil];

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method : checkAndCreateDatabase
// Method to open database
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void) openDatabase
{

        cDatabaseName = @"db.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    cDatabasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:cDatabaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    //-------------------------------------------
    if(sqlite3_open([cDatabasePath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      //nothing
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Method : closeDatabase
// Method to close database
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)closeDatabase
{

    // Close the database.
    if (sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        //NSLog(@"Error: failed to close database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }


}


-(BOOL) removeSegmentWithSegmentId:(NSInteger)sId
{
    //for sharing variables of appdelegate file
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    BOOL isDeleted=NO;
    [self openDatabase];
    const char *sqlStatement;
    sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM segment WHERE segment_id =?";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {   
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, sId); 

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
        {
            NSLog( @"Error while deleting metadata of  segment '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));         

        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Deleted chart segment successfully !");
            isDeleted=YES;

        }
        //-------------------------------------------
        sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);       
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog( @"Error while deleting segment of  chart '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    [self closeDatabase];
    return isDeleted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> delete rows using name from text box.

- (BOOL) deleteRow:(NSString *)name {
  const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

  if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
      NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM person WHERE name='%@'",name];
      const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

  ```
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
      if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
          sqlite3_finalize(statement);
          sqlite3_close(database);
          return YES;
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement));
      }
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  ```

  }
  sqlite3_close(database);
  return NO;
  }

> return Yes if deleted successfully and return NO if fail to delete.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.